# UIView animations inconsistant / laggy when having multiple running?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

Im am experiencing some issues with UIView animations, I'm not sure if this is down to lag or if there is simply something fundamentally wrong with my code (But I'm pretty sure there isn't).

I have 4 UIView animations in the app but only 2 of them should ever be running at the same time. Two of them simply run one after another and never stop unless I call

```
[self.view1.layer removeAllAnimations];
[self.view2.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Here is the animation:

```
- (void)slideDown1 {    
    NSLog(@"Anim 1 Started");
    // This sets the top of view1's frame equal to the bottom of self.view.frame
    self.view1TopConstraint.constant    = self.view.frame.size.height;
    // This sets the top of view2's frame equal to the top of self.view.frame
    self.view2TopConstraint.constant    = 0.0f;
    // If we didn't call this block, the changes set above would take effect "immediately"
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         // Calling this inside of an animation causes the changes above to be animated
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // This block will execute when the animations finish
                         NSLog(@"Ended 2 ");
                         // This moves self.view1 so that its bottom is aligned with the top of self.view
                         self.view1TopConstraint.constant   = -1.0f * self.view.frame.size.height;
                         // This causes the line above to take place immediately
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         if (self.isVisible == YES && !CharacterIsAnimated) {
                             // If the screen is still visible, start the next animation                              
                             if (!isEnded) {
                                 [self slideDown2];                                 
                                 if (!isStarted) {                                    
                                     [self JumpAnimGoingDown];                                      
                                     isStarted = YES;
                                 }
                             }
                         } else if (self.isVisible) {                             
                             jumpWasCanceled = YES;                             
                             NSLog(@"Jump was canceled");
                         }
                     }
     ];
}
- (void)slideDown2 {
    treeIsMoving                        = YES;
    self.view1.hidden                   = NO;
    self.view1TopConstraint.constant    = 0.0f;
    self.view2TopConstraint.constant    = self.view.frame.size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         self.view2TopConstraint.constant   = -1.0f * self.view.frame.size.height;
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         if (self.isVisible == YES) {                             
                             if (!isEnded) {                                 
                                 [self slideDown1];                                 
                             }
                         }
                     }
     ];
}
```

The other two animation constantly switch between each other at random intervals (This is based on a touch event by the player of the app) And each time i simply remove all animations for the 'Character' layer and then run 'UpAnim' and after that it resets to the 'Down Anim' Here they are:

```
 - (void)JumpAnimGoingUp {
    //This means that when the player trys to press the screen before this animation is over it will not run
    CharacterIsAnimated = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         // Calling this inside of an animation causes the changes above to be animated                         
                         if (treeIsMoving == YES) {
                             self.character.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / WidthDivision, self.character.center.y - (self.view.frame.size.height / 5), (self.view.frame.size.height * 4) / 45, self.view.frame.size.height / 9);
                         } else {
                             self.character.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / WidthDivision, (self.character.center.y - (self.view.frame.size.height / 18)) - (self.view.frame.size.height / 5), (self.view.frame.size.height * 4) / 45, self.view.frame.size.height / 9);
                         }
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];                         
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // This block will execute when the animations finish
                         Score = Score + 1;
                         self.ScoreText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Score];                         
                         CharacterIsAnimated = NO;
                         if (isStarted) {
                             [self JumpAnimGoingDown];
                             if (jumpWasCanceled) {
                                 [self slideDown2];
                                 jumpWasCanceled = NO;
                                 isStarted = YES;
                             }
                         }
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
     ];    
}
- (void)JumpAnimGoingDown {
    NSLog(@"IsJump");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
                          delay:0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear)
                     animations:^{
                         self.character.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / WidthDivision, (self.character.center.y - (self.view.frame.size.height / 18)) + self.view.frame.size.height, (self.view.frame.size.height * 4) / 45, self.view.frame.size.height / 9);
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         self.character.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / WidthDivision, CharacterStopHeight - (self.view.frame.size.height / 18) + (self.view.frame.size.height / 58), (self.view.frame.size.height * 4) / 45, self.view.frame.size.height / 9);
                         if (isEnded) {                             
                             self.character.hidden = YES;                             
                         }                         
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
     ];
}
```

As far as I can tell everything should run correctly, but after a few runs of switching the two Up and Down animations the object that is ran by the two Up and Down animations begins to move at a speed inconsistent to the speed it should be moving at (This is only during the 'Down' animation). This is only by a small amount but becomes clear quickly because of the images i use for each of the views, but also the fact that the object on the Up and Down animation should move at the exact same speed as the two objects animated with the 'Slide' animations I first showed you.

If there is something obviously wrong with the code please say, other than that any times on how I can stop this slightly odd bug would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Why is `JumpAnimGoingDown` the only one that starts from current state? Also, usual practice in Objective-C is to use camel-casing with instance methods, starting with a lower case, so `jumpAnimGoingDown`. I'm guessing this is a follow-on to the question you had a couple of weeks ago?

Comment: Yes it is a follow on question, and in terms of JumpAnimGoingDown, the reason it starts from current state is I was trying to insure that when it was canceled using RemoveAllAnimations for the Character it would stay in the position it was when RemoveAllAnimations was called, but it didn't work, I ended up getting the position through the presentation layer, but thats in a whole different method and that is what 'CharacterStopHeight' is (with a few adjustments)

Comment: I also notice you formatted my code. Although I appreciate it The reason it was so spaced out was to make it easier to follow when i was bug fixing. i realise now i should have put it back for this post. Anyway, on the basis you left said comment do you possibly have any idea why this problem may be occurring, if so please say since I am stumped on this one.

Comment: My guess is that you've got a subtle bug that has to do with multiple animation blocks running concurrently. If possible at all, I'd recommend trying to only have 1 animation block running at a time. If they get out of sequence, who knows what would happen?